# javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No matching property definition: PROPERTY

Tags: aem, jcr

When I am trying to set a property to my JCR node I am getting error

> javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No matching property definition: PROPERTY.

I am a newbie to cq5. Please can someone help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you add your code to question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In jcr every node has a [node-type](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/node-types.html) (value of "jcr:primaryType").

Most node-types define a schema of properties that are allowed on that node. You cannot just add whatever property you like. It has to be defined in the schema. If you try to add and persist (commit) a property that is *not* defined, you get exactly this `ConstraintViolationException`.

So here's what likely happend: You've tried to create and store a property named "PROPERTY" on a node that has a strict schema, where that is not allowed.

If you provide more details what you tried to do exactly on what type of node, I may be able to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Additional to that, if you use nt:unstructured as the jcr:primaryType, you should be able to set almost any property name. Though there still might be some reserved names that are not allowed at all.

Comment: Thanks for help! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add property to a `nt:file` for exemple, you have to define a new [mixin](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/node-types.html) type and add it to your node.

This way you can add every properties you want

This simpler way is to create a CND file to define all your properties

```
<mc = 'http://myCompany.com/mc'>
[mc:fileProperties]
    mixin
        - mc:String1 (string)version
        - mc:String2 (string) version
        - mc:String3 (string) version
        - mc:LongString1 (string) version
        - mc:Date1 (date) version
        - mc:Date2 (date) version
        - mc:Number1 (long) version
        - mc:Number2 (long) version
        - mc:Boolean1 (boolean) version
        - mc:Boolean2 (boolean) version
        - mc:Choice1 (long) version
```

and you have to register your new mixin (you only have  to do this once)

```
JackrabbitNodeTypeManager manager = (JackrabbitNodeTypeManager)session.getWorkspace().getNodeTypeManager();
InputStream cndFile = ... // Get you CND file
JackrabbitNodeTypeManager.TEXT_X_JCR_CND );
```

and add it to your Node

```
node.addMixin( "mc:fileProperties" );
```

Here you can do

```
node.setProperty( "mc:String1", "Toto" );
session.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in AEM while I using WKND tutorial.
After download solution package, I installed chapter-8

> org.apache.sling.ide.transport.RepositoryException:
>   javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: OakConstraint0004:
>   /content/dam/wknd/en/contributors/stacey-roswells.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png/jcr:content[[oak:Resource]]:
>   No matching property definition found for jcr:uuid =
>   3f4b3593-7e5f-42a6-947a-80b67263469e Caused by:
>   javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: OakConstraint0004:
>   /content/dam/wknd/en/contributors/stacey-roswells.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png/jcr:content[[oak:Resource]]:
>   No matching property definition found for jcr:uuid =
>   3f4b3593-7e5f-42a6-947a-80b67263469e

we can solve the problem if we remember to click on

**aem-guides-wknd.ui.apps -> properties -> project facet -> REMOVE dynamic web module**