# AEM6.3 nodetypes.cnd causing OakConstraint0004 with deployment of DAM assets via Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: aem, sling, jcr

Sometimes (unfortunately, even after months of investigation, I cannot narrow that `sometimes` down to a reproducible set of conditions) I get this error when trying to Publish DAM Assets to AEM via Eclipse AEM plug-in:

```
Failed publishing path=/content/dam/website-demo/issue-replication/ExampleSVG.svg/jcr:content/renditions/original, result=JcrResult[ success:false, exception: org.apache.sling.ide.transport.RepositoryException - javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: OakConstraint0004: /content/dam/website-demo/issue-replication/ExampleSVG.svg/jcr:content/renditions/original/jcr:content[[oak:Resource]]: No matching property definition found for jcr:uuid = 139d4eeb-4308-4b01-8993-c3cb4f7c34c4]
```

Or, without the long horizontal scroll:

> Failed publishing
>   path=/content/dam/website-demo/issue-replication/ExampleSVG.svg/jcr:content/renditions/original,
>   result=JcrResult[ success:false, exception:
>   org.apache.sling.ide.transport.RepositoryException -
>   javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: OakConstraint0004:
>   /content/dam/website-demo/issue-replication/ExampleSVG.svg/jcr:content/renditions/original/jcr:content[[oak:Resource]]:
>   No matching property definition found for jcr:uuid =
>   139d4eeb-4308-4b01-8993-c3cb4f7c34c4]

After months of false leads, I am finally suspecting that this may be caused by a missing definition in `nodetypes.cnd`. Could that be it? I use whatever came OOTB:

```
<'sling'='http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0'>
<'nt'='http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0'>
<'rep'='internal'>
<'dam'='http://www.day.com/dam/1.0'>
<'jcr'='http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0'>

[sling:OrderedFolder] > sling:Folder
  orderable
  + * (nt:base) = sling:OrderedFolder version

[sling:Folder] > nt:folder
  - * (undefined) multiple
  - * (undefined)
  + * (nt:base) = sling:Folder version

[rep:RepoAccessControllable]
  mixin
  + rep:repoPolicy (rep:Policy) protected ignore

[dam:Asset] > nt:hierarchyNode
  primaryitem jcr:content
  + jcr:content (dam:AssetContent) = dam:AssetContent
  + * (nt:base) = nt:base version

[dam:AssetContent] > nt:unstructured
  + metadata (nt:unstructured)
  + related (nt:unstructured)
  + renditions (nt:folder)
```

What led me to this file is the top answer to this possibly related but ultimately different question: [javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No matching property definition: PROPERTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305827/javax-jcr-nodetype-constraintviolationexception-no-matching-property-definition)

Comment: I can't explain what is going on, but if you are able to eventually reproduce this consistently please file a bug. It definitely looks like one